# VHDL count and shift

Tags: vhdl, quartus

8-bit input value is transferred from Data to A when load is 1. And when S becomes 1, if A(0) is 1, the value of B is increased by 1, and A is shift right. When the value of A becomes 00000000, we make done 1 and escape. Therefore, the number of 1's in the input value is displayed in 4-bit B. What should I do?
I tried to code, but I can't until 1 week.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
 
 entity one_counter is
     port (
         Output :out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
            Done : out std_logic;
            Input : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        load :in  std_logic;  
            S: in std_logic;
        clk,reset_n  :in  std_logic                           
    );
end entity;

 architecture behav of one_counter is 
    signal A :std_logic_vector (7 downto 0); 
    signal B :std_logic_vector (3 downto 0); 
    signal D : std_logic;
    signal state_out:std_logic_vector ( 1 downto 0);
    begin 
    process (reset_n, clk) is begin
            if (reset_n = '0') then
                state_out <= "00";             
            elsif rising_edge(clk) then  
                case (state_out) is
                    when "00" => if  (load = '1') then
                            state_out <="01"; end if;
                     when "01" => A <= Input;
                                    if (S = '1') then
                                    state_out <="10";  end if;
                     when "10" =>  
                        WHILE (A /= 0)  loop
                            if A(0) = '1' then
                                B <=  B+1;
                                Output <= B;
                            end if;
                            A <= '0' & A(7 downto 1);

                        END loop;
                        D <= '1';
                        Done <= D;
                        state_out <= "11";
                    when "11" => if( D = '0') then state_out <= "00"; end if;                           
             end case;
          end if; 
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Comment: `While loop`  is wrong, because you cannot shift whole vector A in one clock cycle.
In state `10` you check if A/=0, increase B and shif A. Next clock cycle you shift A again. Another thing is that Input should be sampled in A only once, not everytime you are in state `01`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your specifications you should process one bit only per clock cycle (if `S` is asserted high), while your code tries to process all bits at once. Moreover you did not understand yet the VHDL semantics: during the execution of your while loop the value of signal `A` does not change, you are always processing the same bit and if `A` is not null the loop is infinite. You should probably read a book about VHDL to better understand how and when signals are updated.

Anyway, the translation of your specifications into VHDL looks quite straightforward, as they are in the form *if condition do that, else do this*. Example of translation into VHDL 2008, assuming `done` shall be asserted high when `a` is all zeros (even after reset):

```vhdl
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all;

entity one_counter is
  port(
    clk, reset_n, load, s:  in std_ulogic;
    input:                  in std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);
    output:                out std_ulogic_vector(3 downto 0);
    done:                  out std_ulogic
    );
end entity one_counter;

architecture behav of one_counter is 
  signal a: std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin
  process(reset_n, clk) is
  begin
    if reset_n = '0' then
      a      <= (others => '0');
      output <= (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
      if load = '1' then
        a      <= input;
        output <= (others => '0');
      elsif s = '1' then
        a      <= a srl 1;
        output <= output + a(0);
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

  done <= nor a;
end architecture behav;
```

Note: it is better to not use the resolved `std_logic` and `std_logic_vector` types if you do not want to model a multiple drive situation (tri-state buffers...). Prefer the unresolved `std_ulogic` and `std_ulogic_vector` types. For the details see, for instance, [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32258267/unsigned-addition-with-counter-doesnt-work/32265076#32265076).

Note: avoid `IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH` and `IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED`, they are not standard. Prefer `ieee.numeric_std_unsigned`.

Note: if the behaviour of `done` shall be different (e.g. not asserted high after reset, or asserted high during only one clock period, or both) you will need one more bit of storage to remember that a `load` occurred. Adapt to your exact specifications.

Note: `output` is also reset when `load` is asserted high; this was missing in your own attempt but seems logical.

Comment: thank you but, I need the B ( one counter) that code doesn't have counter.. but  it's good for me your coment , " output needs  also reset" I resoved my problem.. thanks!

Comment: That code has a counter: `output`. Your intermediate `B` is useless. Give it a try and see by yourself.

Comment: oh I get it now . B is useless. thank you :>